# custom HTML for mobile container in google tag manager

Tags: mobile, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to fire custom HTML from a mobile container in Google Tag Manager.

I'm looking to avoid updating app in app store and trying to replicate website which fires javascript code in it's tag manager container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to fire (or even create) a custom HTML tag in a mobile container because you are not technically working with HTML. If you have your mobile container created, you will notice that when you click to create a new Tag, "Custom HTML" is not available.